# get url of clicked href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click

How can I get url of clicked anchor text everywhere on the page. 
I tried this but it only works for "cls" class but not for any anchor.

```
$('.cls').click(function() { 
//here I need to get href url
});
```

Comment: what do you mean by not working for other anchors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For any anchor in your page you can simply do

```
$('a').click(function () {
    alert($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

This will give you url of clicked anchor text everywhere on the page.

For more details checkout:-

- [Element Selector (“element”)](https://api.jquery.com/element-selector/)
- [Class Selector (“.class”)](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

Comment: Or simply `this.href`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `.attr('attributeName')` to retrieve the clicked element's attribute,

```
$('.cls').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) as below:

```
$(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('href'));
});
```